# Is there a way to test adMob ads with real unitIDs without uploading the app to Play Console?

Tags: android-studio, admob, google-play-console

My app has many types of ads (banner, transitions, rewarded video etc) in it. I have developed my app with Android Studio.

I test them all ads with test IDs as Google says.

After being confident that ads are working, I have changed  test IDs to real IDs.

When I run the app on a phone physiacally connected to my PC, the ads are not shown. Some documents say that "real unitIDs never work unless the app is downloaded from Play Store source". That means I have to upload my app to Play Console each time to test real IDs.

But, loading the app to Play Console for test puprpose is not applicable because;

1. It takes long time to come alive (review period)
2. If I even accept to wait for that review period, when the app become alive, the users may download the bugy app because it is for test purpose and not a confident version.

You may say, if the app works with test IDs then it will work with real IDs bu it is not true.

Because my app works well with test IDs. When I switch to real IDs, banners keeps working but rewarded video ads doesn't.

My admob account and all adUnits seems ok. This is not an issue about my adMob account.

So the question is that, is there a way to test my app with admob's real unitIDs without uploading the app to Play Console and download it from Play Store?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can test your Live Ids.

put this block of code in your splash activity (first activity), run your app you will get something like this in log, test_id replace this in your code...

I/Ads: Use RequestConfiguration.Builder.setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("test_id"))

```
 List<String> testDeviceIds = Arrays.asList("test_id");
RequestConfiguration configuration =
    new RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds).build();
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration);
```

ref:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try out your code. On the other hand, my ads works with test IDs. So this means that my coding is error free. When I switch to live IDs, banners keeps working but Rewareded interstial ads not. My admob is not a new account. All ads units is 'Active'. Admob account 'aproved'. All seems ok in there. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

for Rewareded interstial ads try this code:

make your class... implements OnUserEarnedRewardListener.
if anything goes wrong you will get error message in onAdFailedToLoad, using loadAdError.getMessage();

```
 private RewardedInterstitialAd rewardedInterstitialAd;

@Override
    public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem rewardItem) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onUserEarnedReward");
        // TODO: Reward the user!
    }

    public void loadRewardedAd() {
        // Use the test ad unit ID to load an ad.
        RewardedInterstitialAd.load(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.rewarded_interstitial_id),
                new AdRequest.Builder().build(), new RewardedInterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(RewardedInterstitialAd ad) {
                        rewardedInterstitialAd = ad;
                        rewardedInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                            /** Called when the ad failed to show full screen content. */
                            @Override
                            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent");
                            }

                            /** Called when ad showed the full screen content. */
                            @Override
                            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                Log.i(TAG, "onAdShowedFullScreenContent");
                            }

                            /** Called when full screen content is dismissed. */
                            @Override
                            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                Log.i(TAG, "onAdDismissedFullScreenContent");
                            }

                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onAdFailedToLoad");
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you kind help, Rahul. I have added my device to admob as test device and used your above codes. It worked. Now, the interstial ads  show up on my test device. But I have another problem now. The ad video shown is too long, maybe 30-40 minutes or more. I was expecting to 10-20seconds videos. Is there a settings for that  I missed? By the way, I clicked "thsi was usefull" icon at the left to give +1 points to your post, but it did not accept my attempt as I am new on this platform and have not enough reputation.

Comment: One more thig I forgot to say. There is no close (x) option on videos. So I can not close it.

Comment: Test ads are random, sometimes it will show longer videos, sometimes short. and close video button will be visible after sometime depends on video.

Comment: When I playing games in years, I see videos between each level and all of them are very short (max. 20-30 seconds) . I have never come across a video with minutes long.  Is that different types of video ads? Am I working on a wrong way, I wonder? Because no one waits 10 minutes after finishing one level to move on to the next, right?

Comment: live Admob rewarded ads are limited to 60 seconds.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your time. I have converted all my Video ads to "rewarded Ads" type. Everything seems ok now. By the way, I did not see any information about the video ads lengths in related developers pages of admob and play console. Where did you get that such iformation from? Any link pls.

Comment: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7311747?hl=en